# Fast way to convert byte[] to short[] on Java Card

Tags: java, javacard

I want to optimize SHA-3 algorithm on a Java Card. I need a fast algorithm consuming less memory which allows to easy convert `byte[]` to `short[]` (or short`[]` to `byte[]`). My current implementation looks like this:

```
private short[] byteToShort(byte[] b,int len)
{
    short len_conv  = (short)(len/2);
    for ( short x = 0; x < len_conv;x++)
    {
        for ( short j = 0 ; j < 2 ; j++)
            aux[j] = b[2*x+j];
        temp_conv[x] = (short)((((short)aux[1]) & 0xFF) | ((((short)(aux[0]) & 0xFF) << 8 )));
    }
    return temp_conv;
}
```

where `len` is actual size of the `b` array and `aux` and `temp_conv` are defined as private and allocated as :

```
short[] temp_conv = JCSystem.makeTransientShortArray((short)255,JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_DESELECT); // used during conversion
byte[] aux = new byte[2];
```

I currently use Java Card v 2.2.2

Comment: You might try unrolling the loop a bit: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not reinvent the wheel: there are useful built-in static methods in the Java Card API, often implemented as native functions for performance reasons. Your code cannot be better than them.

1) First of all, [`javacardx.framework.util.ArrayLogic.arrayCopyRepackNonAtomic`](http://www.win.tue.nl/pinpasjc/docs/apis/jc222/javacardx/framework/util/ArrayLogic.html) is what you need when working with a RAM array:

```
ArrayLogic.arrayCopyRepackNonAtomic(b, (short) 0, len, temp_conv, (short) 0);
```

There is also `arrayCopyRepack`, which is useful for persistent arrays (the whole operation is done in a single transaction, but it is a little slower).

---

2) If you cannot use `ArrayLogic`, there is always [`javacard.framework.Util.getShort`](http://www.win.tue.nl/pinpasjc/docs/apis/jc222/javacard/framework/Util.html#getShort%28byte[],%20short%29), which you can use instead of the bitwise magic:

```
private static final void byteToShort(final byte[] bytes, final short blen, final short[] shorts)
{
    short x = 0;
    short y = 0;
    for (; y < blen; x++, y += 2)
    {
        shorts[x] = Util.getShort(bytes, y);
    }
}
```

Note there is also `setShort`, which might be useful for `short[]` to `byte[]` conversion.

---

3) Some other notes on your code in case you really want to implement it on your own:

- Your `aux` is stored in the persistent memory. This is awfully slow and it will probably damage your card, because `aux` is rewritten very often, see [Symptoms of EEPROM damage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30636485/symptoms-of-eeprom-damage).
- `b[2*x+j]` is not effective, because of slow multiplication. You should use two loop variables instead and addition only.
- Get rid of `aux` and the inner loop, you don't need them at all
- What about `int len`? There is no `int` in Java Card 2.2.2...

Comment: About `int len`: There is `int` in Java Card 2.2.2, it's optional. Still, of course, in this piece of code using `int` makes no sense and should be replaced with `short` to not depend without reason on whether or not the implementation supports the optional `int` type.

Comment: In order to deal with NVM wear, for several Java Card Operating Systems it is better to do these operations within a transaction. Then the assignments no longer need to be atomic but can be cached in RAM until the transaction is completed.